# checkbox control not calculating value consistently

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I want to use the feature of the checkbox control by using SSJS to return "true" or "false" based on the value of a session variable.  The calculation only runs when the page is completely refreshed.  The code does not on a partial or full refresh once the page is loaded (The only exception is that the code will run on the first partial or full refresh - which is interesting). I wrote a quick demonstration program.
I am sure this has something to do with the JSF lifecycle, but am not sophisticated in the technology to decipher what is going on.
Thanks,
---Lisa&

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (sessionScope.uncheck === true) {
    sessionScope.checked = false;
} else {
    sessionScope.checked = true;
}}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <xp:panel id="Panel1">
        <xp:label id="label1" value="Panel1" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:label>
        <xp:button id="button1" value="Button1 - Check the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Panel2">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.checked = true;
print("just clicked Button1 sessionScope.checked = ",sessionScope.checked);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:button id="button3" value="Button 2 - Uncheck the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Panel2">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.checked = false;
print("just clicked Button2 sessionScope.checked = ",sessionScope.checked);}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:button id="button2" value="Reload page - Uncheck the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.uncheck = true;
context.reloadPage();}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:button id="button4" value="Reload page - Check the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.uncheck = false;
context.reloadPage();}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:panel id="Panel2">
        <xp:label id="label2" value="Panel2" style="font-weight:bold">
        </xp:label>
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" text="Computed Checkbox">
            <xp:this.defaultChecked><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("Calculating CheckBox - sessionScope.checked = ",sessionScope.checked);
return sessionScope.checked}]]></xp:this.defaultChecked>
        </xp:checkBox>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your sessionScope variable directly to the xp:checkBox. This way any changes to the sessionScope variable will be reflected by the checkbox when refreshed:

```
<xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" text="Computed Checkbox" value="#{sessionScope.checked}"></xp:checkBox>
```

Here's an example using your buttons for partial refresh and for full reload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:panel id="Panel1">
        <xp:label id="label1" value="Panel1" style="font-weight:bold"></xp:label>
        <xp:button id="button1" value="Button1 - Check the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Panel2">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    sessionScope.checked = true;
                    print("just clicked Button1 sessionScope.checked = ",sessionScope.checked);
                }]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:button id="button3" value="Button 2 - Uncheck the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Panel2">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    sessionScope.checked = false;
                    print("just clicked Button2 sessionScope.checked = ",sessionScope.checked);
                }]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>

        <xp:button id="button2" value="Reload page - Uncheck the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    sessionScope.checked = true;
                }]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:button id="button4" value="Reload page - Check the Box">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    sessionScope.checked = false;
                }]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
    </xp:panel>

    <xp:panel id="Panel2">
        <xp:label id="label2" value="Panel2" style="font-weight:bold">
        </xp:label>
        <xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" text="Computed Checkbox" value="#{sessionScope.checked}"></xp:checkBox>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you, Henrik.  I should have tried that as I have used binding to help me out with controls in the past.  The workaround I came up for my application is slightly more complicated.  I have a scoped variable that is set and use the value of that scoped variable to issue either a set or unset the checkbox with "getComponent('componentID').setValue('Yes' or 'No')".  "Yes" and "No" are the values of the checkbox when checked and unchecked respectively.  Still it would be nice if that calculation would run - seems the most elegant.  But, alas - it is only an empty Armani suit.